# How to make Greenplum 4.2.3 only scan the intended partition?

Tags: database, database-performance, query-performance, greenplum

When I uses unnest() in a View, and uses that View in a select statement, Greenplum seems to fail in only searching for the intended partition and search through all the partition of the main table instead. The same thing also apply when using a Subquery instead of a View.

For example:

```
Select something from (select unnest(an_array_field) from table_y) 
where date = 'somedate' and state = 'somestate'
```

We currently have 2 different servers running 2 different version of Greenplum. Server A run on an older version (4.2.1) while the Server B run on 4.2.3. Running the same query above will result differently. Server A (old) will return the query in few seconds while Server B (new) will take forever to return. Running an Explain of the query shows that Server A only do scan on one of the partitions (with the date and state in the where clause) while Server B will do a Scan on each partition, causing the slowness.

The table structure for both DBs are the same. Running a query without the unnest will not have the problem. So, I'm suspecting that there is something to do with new version. Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a newer version of the DB.  4.2.5 is the current version.  An upcoming release will also have a new query planner that should also help if upgrading to 4.2.5 doesn't.

Comment: Could you tell where to get this release or if it is available for evaluation purposes? Looked on the main portal but all I could find was 4.2.2.4

Comment: That's the newest version of community edition that's freely available for download.  For a newer version, you'll have to contact your local Pivotal rep.